# How to retain a CSS element after I change its margin positions using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, backend

I am trying to create a minesweeper game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. To create the grid I am using the following code:

```html
<div id="game-space"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  for(i=0; i<40; i=i+20){
    var k = 450 + i;
    document.getElementById("game-space").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("game-space").style.top = "100px";
    document.getElementById("game-space").style.left = k + "px";
    document.getElementById("game-space").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("game-space").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to update the left margin by 20px every time the loop runs so that I can create a row.

Now, what happens is that like in the example code the loop is supposed to run twice, so instead of showing two blocks of black color it is showing only a single block at the final loop position.

How can I get to retain the blocks as the loop progresses?

Comment: You just update the div's style twice. How do you want to create the grid? Do you want to duplicate `<div id="game-space">`? Where do you declare the variable `i`? Is it a global variale?

Comment: no `i` is not a global variable i have just declared it in the `for loop`, yes i want to duplicate ` <div id="game-space">` i just want it to move by 20px each time, also in the actual game i would like to create a 10 cell row so would i need to run the style 10 times for the final cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `div` element for every box that you want to create. This can be done with

```
var g = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById("game-space").appendChild(g);
```

Here is your updated code with unique indexes on all of the divs

```
<div id="game-space"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var attr = document.getElementById("game-space");
  for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    var leftOffset = 450 + i*20;
    var g = document.createElement('div');
    
    g.id = "game-space-" + i;
    g.style.position = "absolute";
    g.style.top = "100px";
    g.style.left = leftOffset + "px";
    g.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    g.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    g.style.height = "20px";
    g.style.width = "20px";
    g.style.display = "block";

    attr.appendChild(g);
  }
</script>
```